# I need some assistance opening a few videos in VLC on android automatically from my wordpress site

Tags: api, videos, cloud

Im using a dropbox plugin for a few videos and want them to auto open in VLC on android. I just need to pre-pend the vlc:// protocol before the dropbox links. How can I accomplish this automatically for adding new videos in the future.

I tried modifying htaccess file so far but it didn't help. I tried the below.

Redirect `http://wordpresssite.com/app/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=outofthebox-download` `vlc://http://wordpressite.com/app/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=outofthebox-download`

and this as well

Redirect `https://content.dropboxapi.com/apitl/` `vlc://https://content.dropboxapi.com/apitl/`

Neither worked. Can someone please help me? I would be very grateful!!

The video download links look like this if it helps:  `https://wordpresssite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=outofthebox-download&OutoftheBoxpath=%2Fmy_new_bar_commercial.mp4&lastpath=%2F&account_id=dbid:AABfzdssddsdsdsddssFf6E5KozZYulCFIM&listtoken=5b25f0e729e24asfdfdfddfffdba1576ae3cf`

Which redirects to `content.dropboxapi.com`

Comment: Instead of using admin-ajax, create a custom endpoint using the rest-api. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: unfortunately it's not my plugin that i'm using.And this is the only dropbox plugin that will allow my to do certain things so I will need to stick with it. Thanks for the advice though!